# Who influences Forex prices and by how much?

Tags: fx, market-making, currency, financial-markets

May question is probably stupid, however I cannot find some reasonable explanation who (and to what extent) is influencing the prices at the Forex market.

Most of the stuff I found on the Internet sounds more like a conspiration theory and the explanation are not really consistent together.

Basically I would like to know, how big share of the changes in forex market is done by different user classes like: national banks, private banks, forex traders, etc...

I guess there would be some papers about this topic, however I am unable to find something decent (probably I am lacking keywords or other knowledge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the BIS Triennial FX Survey, latest was last year. https://www.bis.org/statistics/rpfx19.htm

E.g. https://stats.bis.org/statx/srs/table/d11.4?o=8:TO1,9:TO1 (table showing "OTC foreign exchange turnover by instrument, counterparty and maturity in April 2019, "net-net" basis")

EDIT: you could also try https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/markets/london-foreign-exchange-joint-standing-committee/results-of-the-semi-annual-fx-turnover-survey-april-2019

Comment: A concise graphical summary of the data here https://www.bis.org/statistics/rpfx19_fx.pdf#page=9 (Clearly it is a big market with many participants, unlikely any 1 dominates IMO).